# При формировании ajax-запроса пропадают знаки "+" из <textarea>

Tags: php, ajax, textarea

Есть две textarea: `<textarea name="in">` и `<textarea name="out">`. В первую (здесь на событие oninput методом POST отправляется ajax-запрос в handler.php) вставляю текст он обрабатывается и выводит отредактированный текст в `<textarea name="out">`. Так вот, когда в тексте есть знаки плюсы "+", то в `<textarea name="out">` эти знаки исчезают - на их месте пробелы...
Даже есть в handler.php будет просто одна строчка `print_r($_POST);` (чтобы посмотреть какие запросы приходят), то `[txt_in]` будет без "+". Если в консоли ввести txt_in.value (ведь именно `'txt_in=' + txt_in.value` из js отправляется в handler.php), то текст будет с "+". В чем причина?

```
txt_in.oninput = function(){
    var data = 'txt_in=' + txt_in.value;
    //console.log(data);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'handler.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState != 4){
            //alert(xhr.readyState);
            return;

        }
        if(xhr.status == 200){
             txt_out.value = xhr.response;
            //txt_out.focus();
        }
        else{
            txt_out.value = 'Не удалось связаться с сервером!';
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: давайте код в студию

Answer (score 1):

`+` переводится в пробел в запросах с `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` как зарезервированный символ. Используйте другое кодирование формы или сделайте `encodeURIComponent(str)` строки

Comment: А если передавать json?..

Comment: Можно передавать в json